# Constructing HTML template in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am constructing a HTML template inside a for loop, I would like to pass variable value in to the template , and build dynamic templates.

Below is my for loop, I need colIndex value to be passed in Span tag of HTML mentioned as "Need colIndex here"

```
for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
    name: 'col-' + colIndex,
    aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
    width: 85,
    treeAggregationType: uiGridTreeViewConstants.aggregation.SUM,
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">'+
                  '<span ng-if="!(row.entity[\'$$\' + col.uid])">{{row.entity[\'col-'+'<<Need colIndex here>>'+'\'] CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span>'+
                  '<span ng-if="row.entity[\'$$\' + col.uid]"> {{row.entity["$$" + col.uid].value CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span>'+
                  '</div>'
  });
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you not just pass it in in the same way you're populating the `name` property?

Comment: I was thinking something more complex and for got the basic String concatenation  ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
name: 'col-' + colIndex,
aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
width: 85,
treeAggregationType: uiGridTreeViewConstants.aggregation.SUM,
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">'+
              '<span ng-if="!(row.entity[\'$$\' + col.uid])">{{row.entity[\'col-'+colIndex+'\'] CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span>'+
              '<span ng-if="row.entity[\'$$\' + col.uid]"> {{row.entity["$$" + col.uid].value CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span>'+
              '</div>'
});
}
```

Comment: Yeah :D .. I realized after posting the question , it was very silly question to ask :) Thanks dude..